# Non-installed usage of SQL Server CE 4.0 in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a wpf application that accesses data within a SQL Server CE database. The application and database are meant to be run on a PC without installation, however attempting to do so fails. (failure to locate db provider)  I've taken the following steps:

- `System.Data.SqlServerCE` -> copy local
- copied 7 SQL Server CE assemblies into application directory
- verified that VC++ is available on system
- added following to `app.config`

  ```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" 
           invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
           description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
           type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>                          
  </system.data>
  ```

On attempted execution of the following code:

```
  try
  {
    MessageBox.Show("initialize db connection");
    context = new DataAccess.PersistentStorageEntities();
    MessageBox.Show(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("exception: "+ex.Message);
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("innerexception: "+ ex.InnerException.Message);  
    }
  }
```

I get the message:

> *exception:  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)*

I suspect it's having trouble loading the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0` , but can't figure out why it would be trying to load as Win32

Any thoughts? I feel like I'm losing my mind here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You must use the System.Data.SqlServerCe dll from the Private folder (and the System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll dll from the same folder).

2: You must add x86 and AMD64 folders to your project, and include the required files (including the private VC++ runtime folder) in each (like in the Private folder). Make sure to include all files as content

3: You must change the config reference to version 4.0.0.1

See my blog for more detailed info: "Using SQL Server Compact 4.0 with Desktop Private Deployment and a Setup project (MSI) (part 2)"

Comment: thanks Eric, I came to this same conclusion after searching for several hours.

Comment: to clarify, you must copy the folder at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Private to the application's directory